# Why does netty provide EpollEventLoopGroup?

Tags: java, netty, nio, epoll

After my test, there is no difference in performance between Netty's `NioEventLoopGroup` and `EpollEventLoopGroup`. Why does Netty also provide EpollEventLoopGroup?

When the server maintains 1000 TCP links, there is no difference between CPU and memory of the server. Here is my code:

```
public class EpollServer {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            logger.info("port:"+System.getProperty("port", "8007"));
            logger.info("isUseEpoll:"+System.getProperty("isUserEpoll","true"));
            EventLoopGroup bossGroup;
            EventLoopGroup workerGroup;
            Class          clazz;
    
            if (useEpoll()) {
                bossGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup(1);
                workerGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup();
                clazz = EpollServerSocketChannel.class;
            }else{
                bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
                workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
                clazz = NioServerSocketChannel.class;
            }
    
            final EpollServerHandler epollHandler = new EpollServerHandler();
            try {
                ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
                logger.info("[socket Type]: {}", clazz.getSimpleName());
                b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                        .channel(clazz)
                        .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 10001)
                        .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                            @Override
                            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                                ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                                p.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1024,0,2,0,2));
                                p.addLast(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler(){
                                    @Override
                                    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                                        ByteBuf content = (ByteBuf) msg;
                                        ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(content.retain());
                                    }
                                });
    
                            }
                        });
   
                ChannelFuture f = b.bind(PORT).sync();
                f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
            } finally {
                bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
                workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            }
        }


    private static boolean useEpoll() {
        if(isUseEpoll){
            return Epoll.isAvailable();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that in "heavy load" scenarios there is definitely a performance difference in:

- CPU usage
- Memory usage
- Allocations

Beside this the native epoll transport also supports multiple features that are not exposed by NIO itself.

Comment: I read the official wiki:  [Native-transports](https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/Native-transports).


The wiki doesn't mention how much performance has improved, and I've tested it myself. How can I test to demonstrate the benefits of epolleventloopgroup？Thank you